# How to "weaken" multiple properties of a type

Tags: typescript

When working with autogenerated class/interface files (through something like Swagger Codegen), it often becomes necessary to modify these models. For instance, suppose you have an autogenerated `HighSchool` class.

```ts
export interface HighSchool {
    schoolTypeCode: number;
    name: string;
    state: string;
    city: string;
}
```

Let's say we create an enum to make working with known `schoolTypeCode` values easy.

```ts
export const enum HighSchoolTypeCode {
    USHighSchool,
    GED,
    OnlineSchool
}
```

Rather than modifying the autogenerated `HighSchool` interface to use this enum, which will be overwritten once autogeneration is reexecuted, I can create my own `HighSchool` interface in a separate file and retype the `schoolTypeCode` by "weakening" it using a helper type, [as described in this GitHub issue response](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3402#issuecomment-385975990).

```ts
export interface HighSchool extends Weaken<HighSchool, 'schoolTypeCode'> {
  schoolTypeCode?: HighSchoolTypeCode;
}
```

Here is the `Weaken` helper type:

```ts
type Weaken<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: P extends K ? any : T[P];
};
```

The limitation here is that only one property can be weakened at a time. Can this helper type be reworked to take in an array of property names? While this syntax might not be correct, I'm imagining it being used something like this:

```
interface WeakenedType extends Weaken<OriginalType, ['foo', 'bar']> {
    foo?: FooEnum;
    bar?: BarEnum;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `Weaken` will do what you want if you pass it a union of the names of the properties you want to weaken, like this:

```
interface WeakenedType extends Weaken<OriginalType, 'foo' | 'bar'> {
    foo?: FooEnum;
    bar?: BarEnum;
}
```